# get user validation cookie from another domain

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I am thinking about creating some sort of senior assassin game at my university, and for that I want to make a portal where users can sign up. The problem comes in when I want to validate their student number against the university directory.

Obviously the university does not have some sort of api for this, and I want to make sure the user is validated (student at the university).

I was thinking that I could create a page with an iframe that goes to our university portal, and sniffs the users validation cookie, but I am not sure if this will work. Is there someone that has experience, or some knowledge regarding this that can lend me knowledge as to how to proceed?

Comment: Does the university have an email system? You could have people sign up by providing name, nickname and univ email, then if they have an appropriate email they get emailed a link where they initialize their account. If they don't have a univ email, you could approve those manually or with a fill in the blank test of some sort.

Comment: @paul duhhh can't believe i didnt see that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The browser does not allow javascript to access domains other than the one where javascript is currently run on. Imagine what kind of a gaping security hole this would be, if it were possible...